# How to compare two Firestore Timestapms in Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on an auction mobile app using **React Native** and **FireBase**. So when a user uplaods an auction that paticular auction will have the status as **pending**. And that auction will have a **start time**. And when that **start time** is reached the status should be automatically update to **live**.For that I wrote a cloud function which will compare the system time with every **pending** auctions **start time** and update the **status**. But my function never goes inside this **if block**.

```
if (isMatching) {
      logger.info("item found");
      await doc.ref.update({status: "live"});
}
```

And here is my full function:

```
export const updateStatus = onSchedule("every 1 minutes", async (event) => {
  const currentTime = Timestamp.now();
  const pendingPostsSnapshot = await getFirestore()
    .collection("Posts_Test")
    .where("status", "==", "pending")
    .get();

  pendingPostsSnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
    const postData = doc.data();
    const startTime = postData.startsAt;
    logger.log("start time", startTime);
    logger.log("current time", currentTime);

    const isMatching = currentTime.isEqual(startTime);

    // Check if the current time is equal to or after the start date
    if (isMatching) {
      logger.info("item found");
      await doc.ref.update({status: "live"});
    }
  });
});
```

**Note:**

- **Posts_Test** is my collection name.

Comment: Use [valueOf()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/firestore/timestamp#_google_cloud_firestore_Timestamp_valueOf_member_1_). From the API docs: Converts this object to a primitive string, which allows Timestamp objects to be compared using the >, <=, >= and > operators.